# PowerShell Script Not Working with Task Scheduler and Outlook

Tags: powershell, outlook, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, office-automation

I've been using a PowerShell script for several years to download Excel sheets from Outlook and save them to a folder. The script has been scheduled using Task Scheduler and has worked flawlessly until recently.

I recently changed my Active Directory (AD) account password and updated it in the Task Scheduler job. However, the task now completes with an error but it doesn't download any files now. Here's the error message:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS\Process_Mailbox.ps1:66 char:1
+ $Inbox = $Namespace.Folders.Item("$MailboxName").Folders.Item("Inbox" ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\PS\Process_Mailbox_RBL.ps1:67 char:1
+ $Archive = $Namespace.Folders.Item("$MailboxName").Folders.Item("$Mai ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Strangely, the script runs perfectly fine when I execute it manually, but it encounters issues when running as a scheduled task through Task Scheduler.

I've checked the user permissions, Outlook profile, and Task Scheduler settings, but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the problem.
It seems like my PowerShell script is encountering issues only when running as a scheduled task through Task Scheduler, specifically related to its interaction with Outlook.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue when running PowerShell scripts with Outlook through Task Scheduler? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does this task run when setted to "Run only when user is log on" ?

Comment: It works fine when I set to Run only when user is log on.
It was woking without the user logged in until I changes my password yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft states the following for automating Office applications:

> All current versions of Microsoft Office were designed, tested, and configured to run as end-user products on a client workstation. They assume an interactive desktop and user profile. They do not provide the level of reentrancy or security that is necessary to meet the needs of server-side components that are designed to run unattended.

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

> If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using a low-level API (Extended MAPI) on which Outlook is based on, or just any other third-party wrapper like Redemption for dealing with Outlook's data from services or task scheduler. Also consider using EWS or Graph API for such tasks because the required data can be retrieved from the backend side as well.

Comment: Thanks for the details about Microsoft statement but if you please check my question I have mentioned that my script is working flawlessly if I run it manually or run with the user logged in. Infact it was running great even when the user is not logged in option was enabled. It started failing when I changed the password yesterday. It did not work even when I changed the password in task. I have mentioned my answer......

But now I just helped myself and it worked...My answer is mentioned below...

Comment: The problem is not with a script, the problem how it was run (under the task scheduler) without a user logged on.

Answer (score 0):

I tried fixing permissions, repairing office, changing arguments in the task scheduler, giving full path of powershell.exe but nothing worked for me.

Finally I realised it was a simple fix - I deleted the Task scheduler job and created it again with a different name and it worked like before :)

Comment: Without a user logged on you may face unpredictable results. Don't forget to mention that as well.