Way to Automate Opening and Closing a Word Doc At Same Time Every Day? (Task Scheduler VBA Script Not Working)
I have tried Task Scheduler, but I can't stop getting the error ActiveX can't create component on line 3:
Dim WordApp
Dim Doc

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Open ("File_Path")

Doc.Save
Doc.Close

Set WordApp = Nothing

MsgBox ("Your Automated Task successfully ran")

I ran RegAsm.exe but no luck. Wondering if there is any other way to automate simply opening and closing a Word doc every day. I have a macro of interest that runs upon opening the doc, so the goal is just to get that to run daily.

Do any of the answers/comments in here help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54131992/how-to-fix-run-time-error-429-activex-component-cant-create-object-error-whe?rq=2 (don't set Task Scheduler to "run with the highest privileges") and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77266391/powershell-script-not-working-with-task-scheduler-and-outlook?rq=2 (are you logged in?)

It's likely to do with how the script is running (OS 32 or 64 bit) versus what Word application is installed (32 vs 64 bit). If you want to workout what you should be doing to debug the problem see this checklist which works for any native COM registered DLL.
